# How do I register transformation change handlers for TransformableNodes inserted when a plane is detected?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I'm adding objects to my scene in ARCore. I'm using the same code (more or less) from the HelloSceneForm repository (https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/hellosceneform/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/hellosceneform/HelloSceneformActivity.java)

```
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
TransformableNode object = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
ScaleController scaleController = object.getScaleController();
scaleController.setMinScale(0.0F);
object.setParent(anchorNode);
object.setRenderable(loadedRenderable);
object.select();
```

Once the object is added, I'm doing some transformations on it. How can I register a handler that will notify me of changes to the object (rotation, translation, scaling)?

I see the `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener()` interface but I don't see how I can connect that to the TransformableNode.

And, I don't see how I could store those changes and then re-apply them to an object after it is inserted. For example, I would like to record an object that has been scaled, keep the scale as some kind of value, and then be able to re-apply that scale value to the object so it returns to the scaled size in the scene. I see that I can retrieve the ScaleController with code like this `object.getScaleController()`. But, the interface it provides seems to give guidance on the scale interaction, not retrieving the actual values or establishing handlers when scale events occur.

More specifically, I want to enter a scene, then in the `setOnTapArPlaneListener` handler, when the plane is detected, I'll add the object. Then I will transform it, and capture those transform values. Then, I will leave the scene, saving those transform values. If I re-enter the scene, I want to wait again for the `setOnTapArPlaneListener` to detect a plane and then add the object AND the transform values captured previously. I get that I might be detecting a different plane, but I'm fine with that.

Comment: So, I see I can use something like `object.getLocalPosition()` to get the position (and equivalents for scale and rotation). But, I don't see how I can register a listener to be notified once a transformation has finished and then query the object.

Comment: `object.setOnTapListener` adds a listener, but it seems odd this would be named tap rather than `setOnTransform` but perhaps there is no abstracted layer to do that calculation for me?

Comment: I guess, `Node.TransformChangedListener` (https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node#addTransformChangedListener(com.google.ar.sceneform.Node.TransformChangedListener)) can help you.